# Message not sent to topic in ballerina/kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ballerina

Im trying to send a message string to a kafka topic(example) but im getting this error

`error: Failed to send data to Kafka server: Expiring 1 record(s) for example-0:120010 ms has passed since batch creation {}`

Producer code

```
kafka:ProducerConfiguration producerConfiguration = {
    clientId: "basic-producer",
    acks: "all",
    retryCount: 3
};


kafka:Producer kafkaProducer = check new (kafka:DEFAULT_URL,producerConfiguration);
public function main() returns error? {
   string message = "Hello World, Ballerina";
    check kafkaProducer->send({
                                topic: "example",
                                value: message.toBytes()});
    check kafkaProducer->'flush();
}
```

How I created the topic

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic example --replication-factor 1 --partitions
2 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Comment: i managed to fix it using an older version of kafka

Comment: Hi, in which kafka version did this fail? I tried out the above code in ballerina kafka v3.0.0 and it worked fine.